# .emacs file issues with org-mode TODO

Tags: emacs, text-editor, org-mode, todo

I am customizing my ~/.emacs file. Specifically, I am customizing org-mode's TODO list feature to include more tasks. However, I keep receiving the following error:

> File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument stringp\ 
>   (sequence "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "DONE"))

I've pasted my ~/.emacs file below. I am every new to emacs and org-mode. Would love any insights.

```
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp -*-                                 

;; Disable the splash screen (to enable it agin, replace th\
e t with 0)                                                 
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; Enable transient mark mode                               
(transient-mark-mode 1)

;;;;org-mode configuration                                  
;; Enable org-mode                                          
(require 'org)
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "DONE")))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))


;; don't create backupfiles                                 
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; don't create auto-save files                             
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

Thanks -- any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Unable to check now, but looks to me like you are mixing different syntaxes. Does it help if you take away the quote before `sequence` as well as one pair of parentheses around the form?

Comment: The same question is also asked on emacs.SE ( http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17838/115 ). You should not be posting duplicate questions.

Comment: @tripleee That syntax is fine. I have this in my config: `(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "SOMEDAY" "CANCELED" "DONE")))`.

Comment: That line causes the todo functionality to halt if I don't remove it.

Comment: It is probably because line 4 is not `elisp` code, and needs to be moved back up to the comment of line 3 where it belongs.